# syntax error near unexpected token `(' in cygwin terminal

Tags: c, syntax-error

I am running the follwong c program related with fork() system call using the cygwin terminal in the windows OS! and i get the following error! how can i rectify this?

```
./fork.cpp: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
'/fork.cpp: line 3: `int main(int argcc,char *argv[])
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
# include<conio.h>
int main(int argcc,char *argv[])
{
    printf("I m %d\n",(int) getpid());

    pid_t pid = fork();
    printf("Fork returned: %d\n", (int) pid);
    printf("I am %d\n, (int) getpid()); 
   getch();
}
```

Comment: wait, are you *compiling* this C program, or are you trying to *run* the C code like you would run a shell script?

Comment: There's an unclosed quote on the third `printf`.

Comment: @dbush problem is that this doesn't align with the error message's line number.

Comment: If it's a C program, then the name "fork.cpp" is quite misleading.

Comment: You didn't compile the program. You're trying to execute the source code.

Comment: can you please copy and paste the **exact** command line you've executed to get the error? Is this **really exactly** the file you've used, or did you modify it?

Comment: how do i compile in cygwin? i am new to it

Comment: With a *compiler*, typically *GCC*. Details depend on the program that you want to compile, so I'm afraid I'll have to refer you to "the internet" to look for a GCC and C programming tutorial. Or you could just use one of the many good, free IDEs that take care of this for you.

Comment: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic fork.c`. If successful, this should produce an executable called `a.out` or `a.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should state the line at which it gives you the error but I am assuming it is this statement : printf("I am %d\n, (int) getpid()); since you have not put the closing quotes in the printf statement ". The unexpected token `(' is the ( just before the word int since the compiler is looking for the closing quotes and can not find them.